a doubt on the proof for $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ is a PID in Dummit&Foote
In Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra, the authors give a proof of $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ being a PID on p. 282 that uses the Dedekind-Hasse norm $N$, which is positive and for any $a,b\in R-\{0\}$, either $a\in(b)$ or $\exists\,r\in(a,b)$ s.t. $N(r)<N(b)$.
In the proof, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are supposed to be non-zero elements in $R=\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$, and $\alpha/\beta=\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}\not\in R$ for some integers $a,b,c$ such that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ and $c>1$. In the case that $c=2$, the authors say that:

Suppose that $c=2$. Then one of $a,b$ is even and the other is odd (otherwise $\alpha/\beta\in R$), ...

But I do not know why one of $a$ and $b$ is supposed to be even: to ensure $\alpha/\beta=\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{2}\not\in R$, we just need to ensure that at least one of $a$ and $b$ is odd, then $a/2$ or $b/2$ is not an integer.

$(1 + \sqrt{-19})/2$ is in $R$ by definition so both a and b can be odd

If $a=b+2n$ for some integer $n$ then $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}2=n+b
\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2\in R$.

Thanks, I misunderstood $R=\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ as the smaller set $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$.
